# Reference specific columns of a pandas DataFrame which is stored inside a Python dictionary object

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing, pandas

I have a Python dictionary of Pandas DataFrame objects that looks something like this (I could easily change that to a list if it makes this better...):

```
 dict = 
 {'Thing 1': df
                      Actual      Error
 Date                                                        
 2014-09-15           140.00      140.000000
 2014-09-15           358.03      230.291656
 2014-09-16           373.04      46.367434
 2014-09-17           427.99      87.622059
 2014-09-18           484.87      94.364759

 ...

 'Thing 5': hf
                      Actual      Error
 Date
 2014-09-15           140.00      140.000000
 2014-09-15           358.03      230.291656
 2014-09-16           373.04      46.367434
 }
```

This makes my keys: 'Thing 1', 'Thing 2',... 'Thing 5' (sometimes these could be non-sequential like the following: 'Hello man', 'You''re nutty', 'Goodbye', '3', 'man'

I'd like to perform operations on the dict such that I return a new dictionary/list of all the values in the "Actual" column.  In other words I want:

```
 dict2 = 
 {'Thing 1': df
                      Actual
 Date                                                        
 2014-09-15           140.00
 2014-09-15           358.03
 2014-09-16           373.04
 2014-09-17           427.99
 2014-09-18           484.87

 ...

 'Thing 5': hf
                      Actual
 Date
 2014-09-15           140.00
 2014-09-15           358.03
 2014-09-16           373.04
 }
```

Then I would like to perform some operations on the resulting dictionary/list such as: groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper..., cumsum(), etc.  I want to AVOID "for" loops at all cost.  I have a solution which uses "for" loops, but it's computationally EXPENSIVE.  I have tried many work arounds, but don't have a clue where to start.  Nothing I've tried has worked.  I've tried a number of variations of using items(), update(), and similiar methods.  Any ideas...?  No "for" loops and/or FAST execution would be very helpful.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want, but how about storing your data frames in a pandas panel?  You could  access columns like this panelname['Thing 1']['Actual']  and do things like panelname['Thing 1'].groupby('Date').count()

Comment: As Bob says, this looks like a pandas panel is better suited for your data structure

Comment: Can you post some code that product dummy data, and your current code to timeit. I think you can concat all the dataframes, the result dataframe will has MultiIndex. Then you can dot the calculation without for-loop.

Comment: Will try to do tonight (ET). I have used concat on dictionaries before.

Comment: Bob, I'm not familiar with pandas panels, but that looks like the way I approached my dictionary in the past. When the keys are sequential (or I force them to be) I can loop through and do exactly what you propose. However, I don't know the names "Thing1", "Thing2", etc., a priori. They are really unique names in a unique order for each user. However, each dictionary item has the same exact columns inside it. I need to be able to reference specific columns (there are actually 6 columns in each of the real dict items inside the dict object) and use the data in those columns to obtain groups etc

Comment: I see.  Well, you could access each frame by an index instead.   e.g. panelname.ix[0]

Comment: I like that idea since it would solve my issue for referencing unique/non-sequential "Things". I still think it would require me to loop through each panel item like I had to with the dictionary. I will follow up with more realistic code tonight if I get a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions to this problem.

1.) When using PYDSE, the cost of using automatic data fitting is high.  Don't do it.

2.) Using a brand new computer instead of a 10+ year old model is always helpful.  Especially when it's a fully loaded, 15", MacPro instead of a budget buy eMachines...

Because of these two discoveries I never officially solved this problem, but thought I should close this one out.